# How to select corresponding data on a different table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a little message system for my college project. In that all the messages are stored in a one table and data related to users are on a separate table. Now I want to first select a range of messages and then find the corresponding usernames related to the selected range. And finally have those data on a array.

Message table

```
Message_id | Sender_id | Receiver_id | Title    | Message
1          | 45        | 20          | Testing  | Hello
2          | 10        | 20          | Testing2 | Hi
```

User table

```
User_id    | First_name  | Last_name | Email | Password
10         | David       | Chang     |dd@bb  | asddsf
.
.
20         | Denis       | Peter     |ff@dd  | sdfsd
.
45         | Night       | Hero      |gg@ll  | asdsa
```

Now I want to get all the data in to an array like this.

```
Message_id=>1
Sender=>David
Receiver=>Denis
Title=>Testing
Message=>Hello
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In terms of SQL query, how do you define the range of messages? what is your criteria?

Comment: uhm you want message with message_id 1 so sender must be Night not david.. hope this is a typo

Comment: @bonCodigo Using something like this 

SELECT * FROM messages_table WHERE Receiver_id ='20'

Comment: @tomexsans yes for the message 1 Sender must be Night Not David.

Answer (score 2):

For you data the query will be

```
 $qry = 'SELECT Message_id, a.First_name as Sender, b.First_Name as Receiver, Title, Message
         FROM Message m
         JOIN User a on a.user_id = m.sender_id
         JOIN User b on b.user_id = m.received_id
         WHERE m.Message_id = 1';

$result = mysql_query($qry)
```

The resulting data will be an array like your requirement.

Comment: Thanx a lot @don this was what I exactly wanted. It's easy to understand as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the SQL portion of the question for you to try:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f42bf/2)

Query:

```
select m.message_id, u.First_Name as Receiver, 
s.First_Name as Sender, m.Title, m.Message
from User u
inner join Message m
on m.receiver_id = u.user_id
inner join User s
on m.sender_id = s.user_id
where m.message_id = 1 //-- your condition
group by m.message_id
;
```

Results based on your sample data in the question:

```
| MESSAGE_ID | RECEIVER | SENDER |   TITLE | MESSAGE |
------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |    Denis |  Night | Testing |   Hello |
```

In MYSQL `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` refers to the same. The reason you need to use user table twice is that your both receiver and senser are users in the user table. So as to say you will need to add proper column alias to the coressponding first names :) too

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudGamal :) long time no see. Let me add that part..

Comment: I am still a sql learner so please kindly explain me. what are these m. u. things?. Can I use what ever I like?. what are they called?.

Comment: `m` and `u` and `s` [are **table alias** =) Instead of using the full table name, you can use these `alias` to refer to the columns from respective tables.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Click on this link to get a better idea of the `alias` You may take a look at the sqlfiddle demo I have added into the answer.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your kind support. You saved my day. Thanx again.

Comment: @Ceylo glad you got it worked `=)` let us know if you have futher questions and happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  m.message_id, m.title, m.message, 
  u.first_name AS sender, u2.first_name AS receiver
FROM message AS m 
INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = m.sender_id 
INNER JOIN user AS u2 on u2.user_id = m.receiver_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a JOIN in your SQL query like this:

```
SELECT msg.Message_id, sender.First_name, receiver.First_name, msg.Title, msg.Message
FROM table_one as msg
JOIN table_two AS sender ON msg.Sender_id = sender.User_id
JOIN table_two AS receiver ON msg.Receiver_id = receiver.User_id
```

Statement above is not tested, just comment if there is any issue with that.